# Trying to place GLOBAL in the right place within Python

Tags: python, function, global

Keep getting a syntax error, trying to understand where and how GLOBAL works within a Python function.

```
import os

path = "start"
route = "1"

def pathcontrol(route, path):
    global path
        while  path=="start":
            if route == "1":
                path = "one"
            elif route == "2":
                path = "two"
            else:
                return


pathcontrol(route, path)
print("Exit Path = "+path)

exit=input("Press enter to exit ")
```

The idea is to add an input() for 'route' as well so the user can choose 1 or 2, but I know how to manage that.

Thanks, 
:-)

Comment: If you're going to use `path` as a global, you don't need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: `if(int(input()==1):#doinput1stuffhere`

Comment: I don't see any obvious syntax errors, but you do have an indentation error; the first line of the `while` loop should be dedented to match the indentation of the `global` statement. As the loop would never execute more than once, it's not clear why you have a loop at all instead of another `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner. removed the arguments and that now makes sense. Otherwise, I guess its confused, should it use the global val or the argument?
Nice One.

Comment: @chepner is giving tricky advice. It would have been better to say: _"If you are passing `path` as an argument, you don't need to use the global variable."_ Or, more generally, it will do you good to *never* use keyword `global`. Treat it as a forbidden word. You can thank me later ;)

Comment: I was going to mention dropping `global` altogether, but the alternative would to replace `pathcontrol(route, path)` with `path = pathcontrol(route, path)` (assuming something like `def pathcontrol(route, path): return path if path != "start" else "one" if route == "1" else "2"`). If you think of the module as a class with a single instance, there's something to be said for thinking of `pathcontrol` as a "method" and `path` being an attribute of the (lone) instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending path in as an argument, as well as declaring it globally. Python does not know now which `path` variable to use: the global or the parameter.

Also: the `global` keyword is considered bad practice. See e.g. Pylint W0603.

Anyway, it's a nice thing to know how works. The following will print `exit path=one` 
 because you are accessing and editing the acttual global `path` variable.

```
import os

path = "start"
route = "1"

def pathcontrol(route):
    global path
    while path=="start":
        if route == "1":
            path = "one"
        elif route == "2":
            path = "two"
        else:
            return


pathcontrol(route)
print("Exit Path = "+path)
```

In the below example, however, you are accessing `path` but not editing it. You're "copying" the one in the global scope:

```
import os

path = "start"
route = "1"

def pathcontrol(route, path):
    while path=="start":
        if route == "1":
            path = "one"
        elif route == "2":
            path = "two"
        else:
            return


pathcontrol(route, path)
print("Exit Path = "+path)
```

And this prints `exit path=start`